# Asynchronous RPC using Spring Boot RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have implemented a basic asynchronous RPC call using spring boot 1.4 and rabbit mq.
My intention is to use this example as a basis of communication
among micro services.
For example, Publisher.java and Subscriber.java could be two micro services talking to each other.

The code shown works fine, but I am curious to know if there are any better ways
of doing this?

My queries as follows:

- For subscriber to listen to request queue using `@RabbitListener` annotation , I did not had to declare `directExchange()` and `binding()` beans in configuration.
   But for `asyncRabbitTemplate` to read response from reply queue, I had to declare `directExchange()` and `binding()` beans in configuration.
  Is there any way I can avoid it, because I feel it is code duplication as I am declaring these beans twice.
- In real world application, there would be many such calls between micro services.And as per my understanding , I would need to declare similar `rpcReplyMessageListenerContainer()` and `asyncRabbitTemplate()` for each request-reply call.
  Is that correct?

Code as follows.
[Link to Github](https://github.com/amardeepkhera/rabbitmq-spring-examples)

#### Config.java

```
@Configuration("asyncRPCConfig")
@Profile("async_rpc")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableRabbit
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"in.rabbitmq.async_rpc"})
public class Config {

    @Value("${queue.reply}")
    private String replyQueue;
    @Value("${exchange.direct}")
    private String directExchange;
    @Value("${routingKey.reply}")
    private String replyRoutingKey;

    @Bean
    public Publisher publisher() {
        return new Publisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                                      SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();

        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue replyQueueRPC() {
        return new Queue(replyQueue);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer rpcReplyMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(replyQueueRPC());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setReceiveTimeout(2000);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }


    @Bean
    public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory),
                        rpcReplyMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory),
                        directExchange + "/" + replyRoutingKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange directExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(directExchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(replyQueueRPC()).to(directExchange()).with(replyRoutingKey);
    }


    @Bean
    public Subscriber subscriber() {
        return new Subscriber();
    }

}
```

#### Publisher.java

```
public class Publisher {

    @Value("${routingKey.request}")
    private String requestRoutingKey;
    @Autowired
    private DirectExchange directExchange;

    private static SecureRandom SECURE_RANDOM;

    static {
        try {
            SECURE_RANDOM = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    private AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate;


    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100 * 1)
    public void publishToDirectExchangeRPCStyle() {
        Integer integer = SECURE_RANDOM.nextInt();
        SampleRequestMessage sampleRequestMessage = new SampleRequestMessage(String.valueOf(integer));
        System.out.println("Sending out message on direct directExchange:" + sampleRequestMessage);

        AsyncRabbitTemplate.RabbitConverterFuture<SampleResponseMessage> sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture = asyncRabbitTemplate
                        .convertSendAndReceive(directExchange.getName(), requestRoutingKey, sampleRequestMessage);
        sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture.addCallback(
                        sampleResponseMessage ->
                                        System.out.println("Response for request message:" + sampleRequestMessage + " is:" + sampleResponseMessage)
                        , failure ->
                                        System.out.println(failure.getMessage())
        );

    }
}
```

#### Subscriber.java

```
public class Subscriber {

    @RabbitHandler
    @RabbitListener(
                    bindings = {
                                    @QueueBinding(value = @Queue("${queue.request}"),
                                                    key = "${routingKey.request}",
                                                    exchange = @Exchange(value = "${exchange.direct}", type = ExchangeTypes.DIRECT, durable = "true"))})
    public SampleResponseMessage subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload SampleRequestMessage sampleRequestMessage, Message message) {
        System.out.println("Received message :" + message);
        return new SampleResponseMessage(sampleRequestMessage.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did some improvements to your answer. https://github.com/janitham/rabbitmq-spring-boot-rpc-worker

Comment: @JMadushan Could you please point out the improvements. It is difficult to see the differences.

Comment: The example didn't work properly with multiple workers, noticed a few message losses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine.

It is not clear what you are asking...

> I had to declare directExchange() and binding() beans in configuration.
>   Is there any way I can avoid it, because I feel it is code duplication as I am declaring these beans twice.

`@QueueBinding` is simply a convenience on `@RabbitListener` and an alternative to declaring the queue, exchange and binding as `@Bean`s.

If you are using a common `@Config` class you can simply omit the `bindings` attribute on the listener and use `queues = "${queue.reply}"` to avoid the duplication.

> I would need to declare similar rpcReplyMessageListenerContainer() and asyncRabbitTemplate() for each request-reply call.
>   Is that correct?

Yes; although with the upcoming 2.0 release, you can use a `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` which avoids the need for a separate reply queue for each service; when you send a message.

[See the documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/htmlsingle/#async-template) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/htmlsingle/#direct-reply-to).

> Starting with version 2.0, the async template now supports Direct reply-to instead of a configured reply queue.

(Should read "as an alternative to " rather than "instead of").

So you can use the same template to talk to multiple services.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I think you have answered all my queries for the time being.I will further post any question if I have any during implemention. Thanks once again.

Comment: I have a follow up question regarding use of `AsyncRabbitTemplate` in context of micro services communicating with each other.
Assume a scenario where micro service A has 10 operation and a second micro service B want to call(request-reply) all of the 10 operations in A.
Since `AsyncRabbitTemplate` can have only one unique `replyToAddress` of the form form `exchange/routingKey` ,
would I need to define 10 such templates(per operation)? Or I am missing something?

Comment: You can use a single template; it will correlated the replies to the correct request - the reply address is sent to the remote service in a header.